# Cannot add geometry layer to QGIS although geometry column is recognized

Tags: qgis, geometry, sql-server

The geometry column `POINT` in the View (not Table) `View_MyGeometry` is generated in the SQL database `GeoData` with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. QGIS recognizes this column as a geometry column in the menu `Layer` > `Add Layer` > `Add MSSQL Spatial Layer ...`. I then manually give `Point` for `Type` and `2056` for `SRID` and continue with the button `Add`. However, QGIS then returns the error message

```
dbname='GeoData' host=[...] srid=2056 type=Point disableInvalidGeometryHandling='0' table="dbo"."View_MyGeometry" (Point) is an invalid layer - not loaded
```

Unfortunately, the option `Vector` > `Geometry Tools` > `Check Validty` ([invalid geometry case](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259256/qgis-invalid-geometry-even-after-using-validity-checker-and-v-clean)) can not be applied as the desired column is not loaded into QGIS at all.

What might be the reason that the geometry column is not valid? Is there already a problem, that `Type` and `SRID` are not automatically recognized?

Technical data:

- SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit) SQL Server, version 14.0.2027.2
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: version 15.0.18206.0
- QGIS: version 3.16.11-Hannover

[image]

Comment: You could use the sql validity check functions